# Reading a file character by character using system calls in c

Tags: c, system-calls

I have no idea how to use system calls but after some search on internet I came up with this code. Can you please correct my code ?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int file;

    open(file, "input.txt", O_RDONLY);
    read(file, ch, 1);
    while (ch != '\0')
    {
       printf("%c", ch);
       fseek(file, 1, SEEK_CUR);
       read(file, ch, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read the [`open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) man pages.

Answer (score 0):

you are almost right in doing, dont need to use fseek inside ,it will be automatically moved.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int retVal = 0;
    unsigned char ch;
    int fdr = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
    
    if( fdr )
    {
        while(read(fdr,&ch,1) == 1)
            printf("%c", ch);
        retVal = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File open failed\n");
        retVal = -1;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```